# How do I edit files in place that were uploaded to Moodle?

Tags: moodle, scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I would like a better workflow for debugging uploaded SCOs.  As things are, I must edit a file in the activity, repackage, upload, and test.  Often, I just need to change a single line of code.  It would be VERY nice to be able to edit that file, that line of code, on the server.  So far, all I've found is that Moodle manages the files, so it seems impractical to locate and decipher the renamed files after upload.

Is there a way to configure Moodle so that it doesn't rename and relocated files in SCOs upon extraction?  Actually, I'm open to any suggestions on the best, fastest workflow for debugging SCOs.

Answer (score 4):

### Problem background

Since Moodle 2.0, files are no longer stored on server in the conventional `/this/is/the/path/to/my.file` way. Instead, files are rehashed and stored in Repositories (i.e. spread all over the `moodledata` folder as a collection of seemingly random data). This increases security and cross-OS compatibility but complicates stuff for people who would like to simply upload a SCORM zip package via FTP. Here's more information on [file handling in Moodle 2.0](http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/File_handling)

### Path to the soluton

Let's locate the file you want to update, then update it.

1. Run phpmyadmin, go to `mdl_files` table, find your file by name in the `filename` field (let's say it's `portrait.jpg`)
2. Look at the `contenthash` field, it'll look like `abcde1234567890`. This means your file is stored in `moodledata/filedir/ab/cd/` folder under the name `abcde1234567890`.
3. Rename the updated `portrait.jpg` to `abcde1234567890`, upload and overwrite.
4. Go back to phpmyadmin and update the `filesize` field in record for `portrait.jpg` with the size of the updated file.

Obviously, this process can be automated. You'll have to write a script that allows you to upload a file, then it'll search for that file in mdl_files, save it to the correct folder and update all fields accordingly.

### Alternative idea

Enable external package type (and also enable 'Update on every launch'). Go to Site administration / Plugins / Activities / SCORM and check the box down below. Now you'll be able to launch SCORM packages directly from another server, so Moodle won't mess with it. Of course, you can run in other (probably cross-domain related) problems.

Answer (score 3):

Sergey's answer is very good, with one caveat:
In his example with the contenthash of `abcde1234567890`, the file is stored in the `moodledata/filedir/ab/cd/` folder under the name **`abcde1234567890`**.  Moodle uses the full contenthash to name the file.

Comment: Your answer should be added as a comment or edit to Sergey's answer.

Comment: Would've added a comment to the answer above, but my reputation wasn't high enough yet to do so.